# What kind of grafana questions are on topic here?

Tags: discussion, migration

I'm monitoring Grafana tag on Stack Overflow, and it has quite a bit of questions, that are in grey zone of on-topicness, to say the least.

Should all (new) non plugin development questions regarding Grafana (and related sub-projects, like Loki) be migrated here? With condition of them not being closable for details or focus issues, of course.

If no, what kind of questions will be on-topic and should be migrated here:

- installation

  - local/server setup
  - docker/Kubernetes/Helm
- helm provisioning
- panel configuration
- dashboard variables
- questions about Grafana in clouds (their own, Amazon Managed Grafana, etc.)